# What can I do to this error with eslintcache?

Tags: reactjs

I am having a problem with a web site compiling. it says that eslintcache is a read-only file so it can't compile. What can I do? Is first time I get this error.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve the problem? For example: Did you try to delete the file? Look if it is really read-only for some reason?

Comment: You need to post your code

Comment: I have not change the code at all and it started doing that.

Answer (score 0):

to fix your problem add the eslintcache file to gitignore like this :

```
      git rm -rf --cached .eslintcache
       git add .
```

git rm: remove files from working tree ...

-r: recursive removal in case of a directory name ...

-f or -force: Override the up-to-date check.
this will fix your issue

Comment: I can't do that because is a read-only file

Comment: post your code I need more details to help you

Comment: I don't know wich part of the code to post because I don't change anything.

Comment: is the .eslintcache file didn't show as a part of your files?

Comment: it doesn't appear in search results when i search it